# Ubuntu emulator requires Ubuntu-one account, still doesn't work after adding

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-emulator

When I install the Ubuntu SDK and emulator, I only get a black screen - the emulator log shows:

```
Loading, please wait...
[    1.310000] systemd-udevd[84]: starting version 204
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
[    2.880000] initrd: mounting /dev/mmcblk0
[    2.900000] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.910000] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.570000] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): recovery complete
[    3.570000] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard
[    3.610000] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    3.630000] EXT4-fs (loop0): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    4.680000] EXT4-fs (loop0): recovery complete
[    4.690000] EXT4-fs (loop0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.690000] initrd: mounting system.img (image developer mode)
[    4.800000] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    4.830000] EXT4-fs (loop1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
[    4.930000] EXT4-fs (loop1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    5.010000] initrd: device is generic
[    6.280000] initrd: checking mount label mtdblock2
[    6.320000] initrd: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 as /root/android//cache
mount: mounting /dev/mtdblock2 on /root/android//cache failed: Invalid argument
[    6.370000] initrd: mounting /root/var/lib/lxc/android/system.img as /root/android/system
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[    9.250000] init: ureadahead-touch main process (260) terminated with status 5
[   37.150000] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[   37.150000] init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
[   37.310000] init: /dev/hw_random not found
[   37.710000] healthd: wakealarm_init: timerfd_create failed
[   39.130000] init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
[   39.130000] init: cannot find '/system/bin/ubuntuappmanager.disabled', disabling 'ubuntuappmanager'
[   39.530000] init: property 'sys.powerctl' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.powerctl}'
[   39.530000] init: powerctl: cannot expand '${sys.powerctl}'
[   39.530000] init: property 'sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes' doesn't exist while expanding '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}'
[   39.530000] init: cannot expand '${sys.sysctl.extra_free_kbytes}' while writing to '/proc/sys/vm/extra_free_kbytes'
[   39.650000] init: cannot find '/sbin/adbd', disabling 'adbd'
[   54.630000] systemd-logind[658]: cgmanager: cgm_list_children for controller=systemd, cgroup_path=user failed: invalid request
```

Has anyone had any success setting up an emulator, and isn't it generally recommended to have Ubuntu on a device for debugging, as is the case for Android? If so, what is the best-supported phone?

**Update-2:**

It must have been some service I didn't restart - next boot after installing the ppa again seems to have fixed it. Unfortunately it seems the accounts tab won't work, and it won't connect to Ubuntu One - which is apparently required to use the app installer.

Is this just a bug, or is Ubuntu-phone going to be like Android, requiring licensing to use the repo?

Ubuntu store in desktop doesn't require an account, is this just a restriction on Ubuntu-touch prerelease?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much success with running the emulator either so I can't help you there but as far as debugging goes, yes, it is better to debug on the phone.

As far as devices go it's best to use hardware officially supported by Canonical. You can find a list of supported devices [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).

Comment: In other words, you can have working Ubuntu-phone as long as it's a Nexus-4?